# Coding a Message using Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Ok, so this problem I've been working on for the past hour, with no answer.

In coding a message, a blank space was represented by 0, an $A$ by 1, a $B$ by 2, a $C$ by 3, and so on. The message was transformed using the following matrix:

$$ A = 
 \left( \begin{array}
{ccc}-1 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1\end{array} \right) $$

and sent as

$$ 
{-19},\ 19,\ 25,\ {-21},\ 0,\ 18,\ {-18},\ 15,\ 3,\ 10,\ {-8},\ 3,\ {-2},\ 20,\ {-7},\ 12 
$$
I know that:
$$
AC = M
$$
$$ 
A^{-1}AC = A^{-1}M
$$

I calculated the inverse to be
$$ A = 
 \left( \begin{array}
{ccc}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right) $$

When i set the encoded Message as a 4x4 matrix, and do the math, I end with

$$-18, 67, -8, 9, -1, -12, -3, 0, -19, 37, 7, -6, -16, 47, -1, -3 $$

Comment: Try encoding the message you decoded by applying the original matrix again; if you get something other than the encoded message you started with, you've got an issue.

Comment: Using mod 26 would make almost no difference within the calculation. Taking the answer i placed above, and converting it to mod 26, would do the same thing because everything is 1 or -1 inside the inverse matrix.

I did calculate to end up the same as the answer above (i changed it from last time)

Comment: Try transposing $M$ and then apply $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slightly ambiguous, but the matrix $M$ was written out in columns not rows.

So, the coded message matrix is actually $M = \begin{bmatrix}-19&0&3&-2\\19&18&10&20\\25&-18&-8&-7\\-21&15&3&12\end{bmatrix}$.

Then, the decoded message matrix is $C = A^{-1}M$. All of the entries of $C$ are integers between $0$ and $26$ inclusive. I'll let you compute it and get the decoded message.

Comment: Thank you. And to clarify, the decoded message is also read in columns (For some reason, i decided to try to read it by rows when it was written out in columns haha)